# Proof of Well-Ordering, without Induction, by the Least Upper Bound Axiom

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, induction, axioms

On, Alan F. Beardon's, 'Limits: A New Approach to Real Analysis' it's asked:

> Show (i) by induction, and (ii) by using the Least Upper Bound Axiom, that
> any set of n real numbers contains a largest element. Show also that it contains
> a smallest element.

I'm not concerned with (i); but I've been struggling with (ii).

I've sketched:

> Take $a = 1 + \sum_{i=0}^n |x_i|$; and any $x_j$.
>
> Well: $a = |x_j| + (1 + \sum_{i \in ([1..n] - \lbrace j\rbrace)} |x_i|)$
>
> So: $\forall i \in [1..n]. a > x_i$, ie $x_{[1..n]}$ has an upper
> bound.
>
> Therefore $x_{[1..n]}$ has a supremum, by the 'LUB Axiom', $\sup x_{[1..n]} = s$.
>
> Suppose $s \notin x_{[1..n]}$; and so, consider $\epsilon_i$ such that
> $x_i = s - \epsilon_i$, $\epsilon_i \gt 0$.
>
> Similarly, $\epsilon_{[1..n]}$ has an infimum, by the 'GLB Theorem',
> $\inf \epsilon_{[1..n]} = \epsilon$.
>
> Take
> $ b_i =  
> \begin{cases}
> 1/2 & \epsilon_i = 1  \\
> 1/\epsilon_i & \epsilon_i \gt 1 \\
> (\epsilon_i)^2 & \epsilon_i \lt 1
> \end{cases}
> $
>
> So $b_i \lt \epsilon_i$ and $b_i \lt 1$.
>
> Now take $b = \prod_{i}^n b_i$; and any $b_j$.
>
> Well: $b = b_j\prod_{i \in ([1..n] - \lbrace j\rbrace)} b_i$.
>
> Since $\prod_{i \in ([1..n] - \lbrace j\rbrace)} b_i \lt 1$, we have
> $\epsilon_j > b_j > b$.
>
> So $\epsilon > 0$, since $b$ is a lower bound of $\epsilon_{[1..n]}$
> and $b > 0$.
>
> And we have $x_i \leq s - \epsilon$, ie $s - \epsilon$ is an upper
> bound of $x_{[1..n]}$, contradicting the minimality of $s$, since $s - \epsilon < s$.
>
> $\therefore s \in x_{[1..n]}$, ie $x_{[1..n]}$ has a biggest element.

However, I might have used Induction in the sketch above, especially while managing:
$a = 1 + \sum_{i=0}^n |x_i|$ and $b = \prod_{i}^n b_i$.

Is it the case that I've used induction in my sketch above?

To me it seems that whenever you have an $A \subsetneq \mathbb{N}$ you can get by without induction; eg in 'Finite Dimensional Linear Algebra', or the question above.

As in:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1311896/940301
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/626648/940301

How would you go about proving (ii), from first principles, without Induction [and without the Axiom of Choice]?

Comment: I don't think we need the least upper bound property for showing maximum of a finite set. The usual axioms of an ordered field are sufficient.